# How do i enable developer option in Samsung z1 Tizen

Tags: tizen

Recently i bought a Samsung Z1 tizen device. I want to start develop app for this device,but i can not find the developer option in this mobile. Can anyone help?

```
    Details about the device info given below:
    Name: Samsung Z1
    Model: SM-Z130H
    Tizen Version: TIZEN 2.3.0.0(Z130HDDU0B0B3)
```

Comment: Thanks @srkushwaha for answering the question quickly. It helped me very much. I also found the answer in                     http://www.tizenexperts.com/2015/01/developer-enable-developer-usb-debugging-mode-tizen-samsung-z1-sm-z130hds/                                                                                                    where a video link is also available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follow this instructions

1. Go into Menu and select Settings
2. Press Home button to return to the homescreen
3. Click the Green Dial icon
4. Type *#84936# – The numbers 84936 actually spell out TIZEN
5. Select Icon on Right Hand Side to enable Developer Option
6. Press Home button to return to home screen
7. Press and hold Home button to bring up recent apps
8. Swipe across on the Settings App to close it
9. Press Home button to return to the home screen
10. Go into Menu and select Settings (again)
11. Scroll to the bottom and select Developer Options
12. Select the icon next to USB Debugging

Comment: Saleh - Do not forget to mark above 'Answer' by @srkushwaha as 'Answer' to your question.